# comparing arrays in php, without caring for the order

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, set

I have two arrays, $a and $b here, and need to check if they contain exactly the same elements (independently of the order). I am thinking of using

```
if (sizeof($a)==sizeof($b) AND array_diff($a,$b)==array())
{

}
```

But I am new to PHP, so I wonder: Is there a better way?

Since I need to use them as sets, maybe I should not use arrays at all but something else.

Comment: It's actually sizeof not size_of

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accepted answer <s>is</s> was wrong. It <s>will</s> would fail on: https://3v4l.org/U8U5p

`$a = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2]; $b = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 1];`

Here is a correct solution:

```
function consistsOfTheSameValues(array $a, array $b)
{
    // check size of both arrays
    if (count($a) !== count($b)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($b as $key => $bValue) {

        // check that expected value exists in the array
        if (!in_array($bValue, $a, true)) {
            return false;
        }

        // check that expected value occurs the same amount of times in both arrays
        if (count(array_keys($a, $bValue, true)) !== count(array_keys($b, $bValue, true))) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Plus quite extensive unit tests: https://3v4l.org/m6lHv

```
<?php

// A unit testing framework in a tweet. https://gist.github.com/mathiasverraes/9046427
function it($m,$p){echo ($p?'✔︎':'✘')." It $m\n"; if(!$p){$GLOBALS['f']=1;}}function done(){if(@$GLOBALS['f'])die(1);}

function consistsOfTheSameValues(array $a, array $b)
{
    // check size of both arrays
    if (count($a) !== count($b)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($b as $key => $bValue) {

        // check that expected value exists in the array
        if (!in_array($bValue, $a, true)) {
            return false;
        }

        // check that expected value occurs the same amount of times in both arrays
        if (count(array_keys($a, $bValue, true)) !== count(array_keys($b, $bValue, true))) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1], [1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, 1], [1, 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1', 1], ['1', 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1', 1], [1, '1']) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, '1'], ['1', 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, '1'], [1, '1']) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 1], ['x' => 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 1], ['y' => 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['y' => 1], ['x' => 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 1, 'y' => 1], ['x' => 1, 'y' => 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['y' => 1, 'x' => 1], ['x' => 1, 'y' => 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 1, 'y' => 1], ['y' => 1, 'x' => 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['y' => 1, 'x' => 1], ['y' => 1, 'x' => 1]) === true
);

it('consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 2, 'y' => 1], ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2]) === true
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1], [2]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1'], [1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1], ['1']) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1], [1, 1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, 1], [1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1', 1], [1, 1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, '1'], [1, 1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, 1], ['1', 1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, 1], [1, '1']) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1', '1'], [1, 1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1', '1'], ['1', 1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1', '1'], [1, '1']) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, 1], ['1', '1']) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['1', 1], ['1', '1']) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues([1, '1'], ['1', '1']) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 1], ['x' => 2]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 1, 'y' => 1], ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 1, 'y' => 1], ['x' => 2, 'y' => 1]) === false
);

it('does not consist of the same values',
    consistsOfTheSameValues(['x' => 2, 'y' => 1], ['x' => 1, 'y' => 1]) === false
);
```

**@update:**

Extensive unit test of @ircmaxell answer: https://3v4l.org/5ivgm

Extensive unit test of @Jon anwser: https://3v4l.org/CrTgQ

Comment: https://3v4l.org/vCPFu - possibility to choose strictness, possibility to skip the optional in_array check, and more tests.

Answer (score 12):

Well, we can do something like this:

```
if (count(array_diff(array_merge($a, $b), array_intersect($a, $b))) === 0) {
    //they are the same!
}
```

The reason it works, is that [`array_merge`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) will make a big array that has all the elements of both `$a` and `$b` (all the elements that are in either `$a`, `$b`, or both).  [`array_intersect`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) will create an array that has all the elements that are in both `$a` and `$b` only.  So if they are different,, there must be at least one element that does not appear in both arrays...

Also note that [`sizeof`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) is not an actual function/construct, it's an alias.  I'd suggest using `count()` for clarity...

Comment: Thanks, that's very elegant. As a mathematician I love it. I am just not sure if this would be faster than Jon's suggestion, above

Comment: I have no doubt it's less efficient, but it's more robust since it'll detect conditions such as @Alin pointed out in his answer...

Comment: It will fail on `$a = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2]; $b = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 1]; `. https://3v4l.org/U8U5p

Comment: why count(array_diff($array1,$array2))==0 won't work?

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer fails to account for duplicates. Here is my take

```
public function sameElements($a, $b)
{
   sort($a);
   sort($b);
   return $a == $b;
}
```

Comment: Very elegant and it works if one needs a weak comparison: https://3v4l.org/7fN7H

Word of warning though, making the comparison strict will lead to `sameElements(['1', 1], [1, '1']) === false` https://3v4l.org/D3af2

Comment: For associative arrays (e.g. `['key' => 'value']`), you can use `asort` instead of `sort`, to keep the keys (`sort` discards the keys).

Answer (score 3):

**If you think of the arrays as sets**:

Then your approach is *almost* correct (you need to drop the equality test for the element count).

**If it matters that the arrays contain multiple copies of the same element**:

Then your approach is *not* correct. You need to sort the arrays with [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and then compare them with `===`. This should be faster, as it can abort the comparison the moment it sees one difference without going over the whole arrays.

**Update:**

Clarified exactly when the OP's approach would be correct or not, also incorporated the suggestion that `sort` would be probably better than `asort` here.

Comment: +1 That would be my suggestion too. It's the equivalent of calling `strtolower` to do case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: He wants to use them as sets. `sort` would be the needed function in that case, not `asort`.

Comment: indeed I miss Python's set :-).

Comment: @ring0: Alin does have a point, but it really depends on whether you want a set in the mathematical sense or an array. I think the answer now covers both cases correctly.

Comment: @Jon Solution with sorting won't work if one need strict types checks, this two arrays won't be considered the same: `['1', 1], [1, '1']` or this two: `[1, '1'], ['1', 1]`. Tests: https://3v4l.org/CrTgQ

Comment: @Isinlor: sure, it depends on how you translate "exactly the same elements" in the question text.

Answer (score 2):

Just for your amusement I'll add an example that demonstrates that your conditions is not correct:

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 1, 2);
$b = array(1, 2, 3);

var_dump(sizeof($a)==sizeof($b) AND array_diff($a,$b)==array());
?>
```

[Test it.](http://codepad.org/p3SraSH1)

I would suggest using a different model. Maybe adding the elements as keys of the array, but this is possible only if they are integers or strings.

```
$arr['itemA'] = true;
$arr['itemB'] = true;
```

This will enforce uniqueness. With this model you can use your condition on `array_keys($arr)`.

Comment: Thank you!! And thank you for showing me codepad. It looks like I will need it in future. Any guess why my solution is not ok?

Comment: no -1 since a good find, but this really should have been a comment (or at least to be an answer should specify a possible fix)...

Comment: @Pietro because you assume that arrays can't contain the same element multiple times, but, as I did in the example, they can. If you want to enforce uniqueness you may want to add the elements as keys with some default value, say `true`. But will be possible only if the keys [integers or strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Thanks! (Actually in my program I would have been right in my assumption, but as you noticed, I am thinking of those arrays as sets, which is a dangerous practice)

Comment: @ircmaxel Because Pietro was convinced that his solution is valid: "Is there a **better** way?", I though a separate post with this was necessary. As for an alternative, I'll add one soon.

Answer (score 0):

A decade has passed since asked, but I stumbled upon kind of similar challenge and I want to share my own solution that also works for multi-dimensional array:

```php
public static function isSame($a, $b, bool $is_strict = true): bool
{
    // check PHP evaluation first
    if ($is_strict ? ($a === $b) : ($a == $b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // comparing scalar is done above, now recursive array comparison
    if (!is_array($a) || !is_array($b))
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ([[$a, $b], [$b, $a]] as [$x, $y])
    {
        foreach ($x as $xkey => $xval)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($xkey, $y))
            {
                return false;
            }
    
            if (!self::isSame($xval, $y[$xkey], $is_strict))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```