# compare two arrays where values are not in same order

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Is there a fast way of doing something like this [Compare two arrays with the same value but with a different order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709494/compare-two-arrays-with-the-same-value-but-with-a-different-order) in PHP?

I have arrays with potentially same data but in different order and I just need to see whether they are identical.

OK, turns out I get back an object and not an array, I guess...

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)#560 (9) etc.
```

hmm... Would the easiest way perhaps to iterate over the contents of the collection in order to create my own array and then compare like you all suggested?

Just adding code for my final solution

```
        //Find out if container receives mediasync
        $toSync = array();
        foreach($c->getVideosToSync() as $v) {
            $toSync[] = $v->getId();
        }

        $inSync = array();
        foreach($c->getVideosInSync() as $v) {
            $inSync[] = $v->getId();
        }

        $noDiff = array_diff($toSync, $inSync);
        $sameLength = count($toSync) === count($inSync);

        if( empty($noDiff) && $sameLength ) {
           $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['syncing'] = false;
        }
        else {
            $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['syncing'] = true;    
        }
```

Comment: Whether the values are identical with different keys, whether the values of one array exist in the second array, whether the count of the array is the same or whether the keys are identical? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Whether the values are identical with different keys, whether the values of one array exist in the second array. what is the difference between these?

Comment: Numeric arrays or associative arrays? With/without repetitions? Cna you post an example? Thx.

Comment: arrays of objects (doctrine entities)

Comment: @MattiasSvensson Almost identical. Second one is when the array being matched is smaller than the second array hence "exists" as you didn't indicate if the arrays were the same size: `potentially same data` :)

Comment: hmm... se update. Would the easiest way perhaps to iterate over the contents of the collection in order to create my own array and then compare like you all suggested?

Comment: I was going to check the other answer off as solution but then it disappeared... I guess both works but the other one had comparison for length as well..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing arrays in php, without caring for the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519847/comparing-arrays-in-php-without-caring-for-the-order)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just get them in a uniform order using [`sort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) & then diff with them with [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

```
# Set the test data.
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,9,10,11);
$array2 = array(3,4,2,6,7);

# Copy the arrays into new arrays for sorting/testing.
$array1_sort = $array1;
$array2_sort = $array2;

# Sort the arrays.
sort($array1_sort);
sort($array2_sort);

# Diff the sorted arrays.
$array_diff = array_diff($array1_sort, $array2_sort);

# Check if the arrays are the same length or not.
$length_diff = (count($array1) - count($array2));
$DIFFERENT_LENGTH = ($length_diff != 0) ? true : false;

# Check if the arrays are different.
$ARE_THEY_DIFFERENT = ($array_diff > 1) ? true : false;

if ($DIFFERENT_LENGTH) {
  echo 'The are different in length: ' . $length_diff;
}
else {
  echo 'They have the same length.';
}
echo '<br />';

if ($ARE_THEY_DIFFERENT) {
  echo 'They are different: ' . implode(', ', $array_diff);
}
else {
  echo 'They are not different.';
}
echo '<br />';
```

Comment: Why sorting before diffing? Your answer suggest exactly the same than my while it introduces the unecessary `sort()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way:

```
<?php

$arrayOld=array(
    '1'=>'32',
    '2'=>'34',
    '3'=>'36',
    '4'=>'38',
    '5'=>'40',
    '6'=>'42',
    '7'=>'44',
);

$arrayNew=array(
    '2'=>'32',
    '1'=>'34',
    '3'=>'36',
    '4'=>'38',
    '5'=>'46',
    '6'=>'42',
    '7'=>'44',
);

/**
 * Here we check if there is any difference in keys or values in two arrays
 * array_intersect_assoc - returns values that are same in both arrays checking values as well as keys
 * array_diff returns the difference between the arrayNew values and those same values in both arrays, returned by array_intersect_assoc
 */
$result = array_diff($arrayNew,array_intersect_assoc($arrayOld, $arrayNew));
print_r($result);


//result is:
Array ( 
    [2] => 32, 
    [1] => 34,
    [5] => 46,
)
```

/** We can see, that the indexes are different for values 32 and 34
* And the value for index 5 has also changed from 40 to 46
*/